# Reading Image metadata from input stream

Tags: java, android

I'm reading **jpg's** exif metadata in *Android* from url. This seems to work very well with emulator but with mobile phone it crashes

> Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(Unknown Source)

```
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
   try {
      InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
      Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(bis);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      //..
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: try ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(bis,true);

Comment: I tried that but it cannot resolve method then. Could it be that it is not supported in this version of the library (2.8.1).

Comment: i went to this link i never used it i just thought id give it a shot http://metadata-extractor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Javadoc/com/drew/imaging/ImageMetadataReader.html

Comment: it says it takes a File as one parameter and then a BufferedInputStream and a boolean parameter in another overload, i dont know what to tell you maybe thats out of date